# Fill space between walls (separate divs)

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, svg

I'm working on a roomplanner in jQuery. Users can drag walls (every single wall is a separate div) and drag furniture into the room. Take a look at the screenshot:

[image]

The half-transparent white div you see between the walls are actually 2 divs wich sizes and positions get changed if a user drags a wall. Another screenshot:

[image]

This works but gives me too much headache with other shapes (u-shape). Is there a simple way to fill up the space between all the walls?

I'v tried to draw with SVG and Canvas but it's not easy to convert the wall-positions to lines and shapes.

```
var svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">';
svg+= '<path style="fill:#f00;" d="M 105,0 L 220,0 L 220,120 L 195,120 L 195,40 L 130,40 L 130,120 L 10,120 L 10,0 z" />';
svg+= '</svg>';

$('#floor').prepend(svg);
```

I have all positions off all walls like this:

```
var wallX = parseFloat($('.wall').css('left').replace('px',''));
var wallY = parseFloat($('.wall').css('top').replace('px',''));
var wallX2 = parseFloat($('.wall').css('left').replace('px',''))+parseFloat($('.wall').css('width').replace('px',''));
var wallY2 = parseFloat($('.wall').css('top').replace('px',''))+parseFloat($('.wall').css('height').replace('px',''));
```

Comment: Added some code to draw an u-shaped svg.

Comment: With the HTML/div approach, have you tried defining walls as div borders? That would be the obvious way to do it.

Comment: Yes, I did that at first. But, for example, an u-shape needs 3 divs for that and a T-shape 2 divs. If I drag one certain wall from an u-shape in one certain way, it becomes a T-shape so I don't think that will work..

Comment: You would need a mechanism for managing the borders to suppress non-existent walls.

Comment: A more complete answer is that you should either (a) draw room-rectangles with borders for walls, or (b) draw wall-rectangles to form enclosed room-spaces. As it stands, you are trying to do both, which seems like at least double the work.

Comment: In the roomplanner I'am able to drag windows/doors on the walls. I can only drop them on walls. Is this als possible on borders? Don't you think drawing an svg or canvas is easier?

Comment: For rectilinear plans, I would use HTML, because it's block elements are naturally rectilinear. SVG would allow more flexibility of shapes but I don't think the logic gets any easier - and probably harder.

Comment: Got it working now. I was pretty far programming the floorplanner so didn't want to change a lot. I changed my floor-calculation. The theory behind the calcution now is that the code loops throught every vertical wall and starts a new div. Every next vertical wall it stops the previous div. The position and size of the floor-divs will be calculated by positions and heights of the wall-divs.

Comment: Rob, that sounds like it should be robust.